# Math.random JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток!

Пишу 'гирлянду' которая рандомно генерирует количество кружков. Изначально их бэкграунд пустой. На клик по кнопке, кружкам по очереди задаю цвет. И вот тут у меня проблема:

Кружки то генерирую, но почему-то последний имеет значение undefined, и цвета(которые тоже рандомно генерируються) применяються как раз к последнему елементу, а должны ко всем.

Подскажите где я прошляпил и что не так написал.

p.s. и как убрать цифровые значения с кружков=)?

```js
'use strict';

const circles = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  circles[i] = i;
}

let circleWrapper = [];
let mainWrapper = document.getElementById('main-wrapper');

for (let i = 0; i <= circles.length; i++) {

  let randomCircle = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100));
  circles.splice(randomCircle, 1);

  circleWrapper = document.createElement('div');
  circleWrapper.classList.add('circle-body');
  circleWrapper.innerHTML = circles[i];
  mainWrapper.appendChild(circleWrapper);
}

const color = [generateColor()];

function generateColor() {
  return '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)
}

function changeColorBtn() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= circles.length; i++) {
    color[i] = generateColor();
    circleWrapper.style = "background-color: " + color[i];
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Calibri;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.circle-body {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #444444;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.btn-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-wrapper button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: gray;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-wrapper button:hover {
  background: dodgerblue;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(176, 176, 176, 1);
}

.btn-wrapper button:active {
  background: darkcyan;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Random</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Garland</h1>

  <div id="main-wrapper">

  </div>

  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <button id="changeBtn" onclick="changeColorBtn()">Click</button>
  </div>


  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так ?

```js
'use strict';

const mainWrapper = document.getElementById('main-wrapper'),
  // генерируем рандомное количество кружков
  circlesCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100)),
  circles = []

console.log(`Generated ${circlesCount} circles`)

// вставляем нужное количество кругов в разметку
for (let i = 0; i < circlesCount; i++) {
  let circleWrapper = document.createElement('div')
  circleWrapper.classList.add('circle-body')
  mainWrapper.appendChild(circleWrapper)
  // каждый новый круг добавляем в массив
  circles.push(circleWrapper)
}

function generateColor() {
  return '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)
}

function changeColorBtn() {
  circles.forEach(c => c.style.backgroundColor = generateColor())
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Calibri;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.circle-body {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #444444;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.btn-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-wrapper button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: gray;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-wrapper button:hover {
  background: dodgerblue;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(176, 176, 176, 1);
}

.btn-wrapper button:active {
  background: darkcyan;
}
```

```html
<h1>Garland</h1>
<div id="main-wrapper">
</div>
<div class="btn-wrapper">
  <button id="changeBtn" onclick="changeColorBtn()">Click</button>
</div>
```

ПС: Честно говоря я не совсем понял что и зачем происходит у вас в коде, поетому ориентировался на то что должно быть

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Это то что я хотел написать, но исходя из того что запас знаний у меня пока-что скудный, написал ерунду=) Я изначально не правильно подошел к рандомизации кругов, а дальше все пошло не в ту степь) Теперь осталось запустить цвета по очереди)) Еще раз СПАСИБО!=)

Answer (score 2):

Давайте разберём Ваш скрипт:

1. Чтобы не было undefined, в строчке `for (let i = 0; i <= circles.length; i++) {` нужно убрать `=`, оставив `i < circles.length` (ну, либо написать `i <= circles.length-1`)
2. Чтобы не было чисел в кружках, надо убрать строчку `circleWrapper.innerHTML = circles[i]`
3. Дальше не очень понятно, что это значит: `const color = [generateColor()]` - ???
4. Ну и, наконец, финальный аккорд - функция `changeColorBtn()`. Первое, что бросается в глаза - `circleWrapper.style = "background-color: " + color[i]`. Вообще-то фон мы должны задавать кружкам, а не обёртке. А для того, чтобы это сделать, сначала надо получить эти кружки (у Вас в коде вообще нет такой строчки): `let circleBody = document.querySelectorAll('.circle-body')`. Дальше `color[i] = generateColor()` опять непонятно что значит. Поэтому напишем `circleBody[i].style = "background-color: " + generateColor()`.

```js
const circles = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  circles[i] = i;
}

let circleWrapper = [];
let mainWrapper = document.getElementById('main-wrapper');

for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {

  let randomCircle = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100));
  circles.splice(randomCircle, 1);

  circleWrapper = document.createElement('div');
  circleWrapper.classList.add('circle-body');
  //circleWrapper.innerHTML = circles[i];
  mainWrapper.appendChild(circleWrapper);
}

function generateColor() {
  return '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)
}

let circleBody = document.querySelectorAll('.circle-body');

function changeColorBtn() {
  for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    //color[i] = generateColor();
    //circleWrapper.style = "background-color: " + generateColor();
    circleBody[i].style = "background-color: " + generateColor();
  }
}

changeBtn.onclick = function(){
  changeColorBtn();
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Calibri;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.circle-body {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #444444;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.btn-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-wrapper button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: gray;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-wrapper button:hover {
  background: dodgerblue;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(176, 176, 176, 1);
}

.btn-wrapper button:active {
  background: darkcyan;
}
```

```html
  <h1>Garland</h1>
  <div id="main-wrapper"></div>

  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <button id="changeBtn">Click</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный разбор=) Я новичок, потому и придумываю разные глупости, логичные на мое скудное мнение)) Все подправил, но заметил такую тенденцию , что кружков генерируется 50-60, не более и не менее(а последний всегда белый. Думаю что проблема в самом подходе рандомизации кругов.